# Problem with "FunctionCompile"

Tags: windows, function-compile

MMA version 13.1 Windows 10

Can someone explain why the following compiles:

```
f = Function[{}, Table[i, {i, 2}]];
FunctionCompile[f]
```

But if we have 2 iterators it does no more compile:

```
f = Function[{}, Table[i + j, {i, 2}, {j, 2}]];
FunctionCompile[f]
```

Comment: [It works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjsob.png) in 12.3.

Comment: Thanks, I have 13.1.

Comment: It also [works in 13.1 (Cloud)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYiqD.png). What is the error message you are getting and which OS are you using?

Comment: It works for me in 13.1 for macos.

Comment: It seems to be Windows specific, since it works on Linux (Cloud) and MacOS.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on Windows... what is the error message that you see?

Comment: Works for me on Windows 10 and 13.1 "13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"